# getting no Login Screen in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

Whenever I start my system, it boots and then redirects me to a black and white screen terminal instead of Login screen. The following information I get on the black and white screen.

```
/dev/sda6: clean, 201186/3973120 files, 15865088/15869184 blocks
```

How can I get my system redirect to the login screen? By hitting f4 I get the access to the terminal and I could login there.

Comment: just previous to this did you you install graphics drivers ?   Nvidia or AMD ?  if so this can be solved by reverting back to open source nouveau drivers which is just a few terminal commands

Comment: No i didn't install any graphic drivers

Comment: previous to this did you issue any  `apt-get remove xxx`  which will result in this if you say remove the various desktop packages

Answer (score 2):

get into the console using ... ctrl-alt-F1 ... login ... then issue

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity

sudo reboot now
```

**P.S.** above trick to reach the console prompt also works for ctrl-alt-F1 through F6 whereas ctrl-alt-F7 will return you back to your normal desktop session